# I can't find a simple filter for my pyth triples filter

Tags: python

I want to filter it down to just primitive triples ([3,4,5], [7,24,25], etc.) nothing non-primitive like [6,8,10] and I can't seem to figure it out, so in my code I just took out my attempts at this filter, and it displays primitive and non-primitive triples.

```
import Tkinter
import sys
from fractions import gcd


def func(event):
    x = int(e1.get())  # get max number
    result = []
    for a in range(1, x):  # loops to get each value in range of x
        for b in range(a, x):
            for c in range(b, x):
                if a**2 + b**2 == c**2 and gcd(a, b) == 1:  # if it is a primitive pyth triple, append result
                    result += ['[',a,',',b,',',c,']']  # add group of triples to list
    l = Tkinter.Message(root, text=result).grid(ipadx=5, ipady=5, sticky='W''E')  # display each group of triples to root
    l0 = Tkinter.Label(root, text="Non-primitive and primitive triples").grid(ipadx=5, ipady=5, sticky='W''E')
    root.bind('<Return>', close)  # Hit enter to exit, only temp for debugging, will reassign to button later


def close(event):  # close program, define parameter event to allow for binding
    Tkinter.sys.exit(0)
    sys.exit(0)


root = Tkinter.Tk()  # establish main gui
root.title('Generator')
e1 = Tkinter.Entry(root)
assert isinstance(e1, object)  # only method I've found to allow for Entry().grid()
e1.grid(ipadx=5, ipady=5, sticky='W''E')
root.bind('<Return>', func)  # bind to Enter, cleaner and quicker than a button
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import gcd (`from fractions import gcd`) and add another test to the line where you check if the triple is Pythagorean like this:

`if a**2 + b**2 == c**2 and gcd(a, b) == 1:`

That should produce only primitive triples.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`fractions.gcd()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html#fractions.gcd) to determine whether a given triple has any common divisor.